# Convert SQL with multiple From in Rails Active Records (same Model associated twice)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to convert the following statements (that work) into something "more elegant" using Active Records.

```rb
query = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT places.id) as total_places
     FROM trips, places
     WHERE trips.id in (?)
      AND (places.id = trips.from_place_id 
        OR places.id = trips.to_place_id)"
Place.find_by_sql([query, @trips.ids]).first.total_places
```

Models look like

```rb
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :from_place, :class_name => 'Place'
    belongs_to :to_place,   :class_name => 'Place'

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :from_place_trips, :class_name => 'Trip', :foreign_key => 'from_place_id'
has_many :to_place_trips,   :class_name => 'Trip', :foreign_key => 'to_place_id'
```

Basically I want to count the number of different Places of a collection of Trips.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated !

**Update:**
Best I've come up so far still looks a bit ugly to me (it fires up 3 SQL requests):

```rb
Place.where('id IN (?) OR id IN (?)'
          , @trips.pluck(:from_place_id)
          , @trips.pluck(:to_place_id)).distinct.count
```

I could also do a simple

```rb
( @trips.pluck(:from_place_id) | @trips.pluck(:to_place_id)).count
```

But that defeat my purpose of using ActiveRecord up to its potential.

Any simpler elegant solution in ActiveRecords?

Comment: hey you need to learn active record in rails first. that will help you a lot http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Hi @NitinJ, I do indeed use ActiveRecord for everything else but having trouble with that particular request. I've updated my question with what I've come up with so far in ActiveRecord.